# Regex to validate alphanumeric, underscores and hyphens with no spaces and only 40 characters

Tags: regex, validation

I wanted to know how I can specify character count for my regex. 
I have the correct regex, I only need to make sure this will work validating zero to fourty characters.

here is the regex

`$fnameRegex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9{0,40}-_]+$/";`

i might have put the `{0,40}` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$fnameRegex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,40}$/";
```

Everything in a character class `[]` will only match one character. You put the quantity limiter outside it (you previously had `+` which is 1 or more - replace it with {0, 40} which is between 0 and 40).

Also I escaped your `-` character in your character class, or else it will be interpreted as a range.

I also recommend to you the great [regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) website which is good for interactively playing around with regex.

Comment: i heard funny things happen when you escape a dash bar

Comment: really? bad things happen when you *don't* escape a dash that is meant to be a literal dash in a character class. If you don't want to escape it for some reason, then put it at either the start or the end of the character class so there is no ambiguity: `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Comment: I have tried above pattern but there is allowed space in between word so how to avoid spaces also...

Answer (score 1):

try
**[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}**
this will check 40 characters of alpha numeric with upper and lower case

Answer (score -2):

What about this?

```
^(\d){0,40}$
```

\d matches only digits
{0,40} indicates that the previous expression (\d) can be present from 0 to 40 times.

You can use this tool to check your regex. It can be useful:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Hope this helps